# lubuntu 16.04 vpn missing icon

Tags: 16.04, lubuntu, network-manager, icons, vpn

After installing 16.04 Lubuntu, I connected to my vpn server. however, the icon in the lower right corner stays the same. in other words, to the naked eye it appears that I have a standard internet connection. I have verified that i am in deed connected to my vpn server.

On Lubuntu 14.04, when connecting to my vpn servers, the icon changes and shows a little yellow padlock on top my internet icon.Knowing when I drop my vpn connection is a pretty big deal.

Any help is really appreciated. J

Answer (score 1):

I faced the exact same issue.
I solved this by selecting another icon theme in the appearance.
I chose to use an icon these called "Humanity" which looks somewhat like Ubuntu Unity icons and these had an changing icon for vpn-connections.